# How do I see the source code of the C header files?

Tags: c++, c, bash, header-files

I want to see some specifications for some functions and structs. In the tutorial I'm going through, it says

```
see the gdk/gdkkeysyms.h header file for a complete list of GDK key codes.
```

I remember that I once (by accident) opened the file for  **math.h**  but I've looked for them with the

```
find -name 
find -wholename
```

commands in Bash and haven't been able to, and internet hasn't solved my problems.

Comment: Then you are not using the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command right? Also try the [`locate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html) command

Comment: Try `/usr/include/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h`

Comment: `find / -name gdkkeysyms.h` (if you aren't doing this as root, then you might want to add `2>/dev/null` to the end of that :P) Or even better, `find /usr/include -name gdkkeysyms.h` (only if you know it's in that directory, because as +πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, it could be in `/usr/local/include`, `/opt` [possibly `/opt/gdk (name of package/application)/include` or I've seen even just `/opt/include` before], or something like `~/include`... so if you aren't sure you can just search `/` [the whole system] or use `locate` [as long as `updatedb` has been ran since installing the files :P]).

Comment: Your chosen code editor/IDE should be able to "follow" *#include* files, so just put cursor on the header name in your source file and do relevant "go to name under cursor" action. If your programming environment can't do this, consider ways to make it possible (up to switching to different editor/IDE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a system where `gcc` is installed, you can get the included C preprocessor to print out the complete paths of all include files. Of course, that assumes that you have the header file installed in such a way that `gcc` can find it.

For a simple system header file, you can extract the path easily:

```
$ cpp -H -o /dev/null - <<<'#include <sys/time.h>' |&head -n1
. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h
```

**Note 1**: The `|&head -n1` causes only the first line of the output -- which is directed to `stderr` -- to be printed. The full output contains the entire include tree, with dots indicating include depth.

**Note 2**: The above assumes that you are using C. If the header is C++, you need to tell `cpp`, using the `-x` flag:

```
$ cpp -H -o /dev/null -x c++ - <<<'#include <vector>' |&head -n1
. /usr/include/c++/5/vector
```

---

For a library whose header files require an `-I` option, you could try using `pkg-config` to find the correct compiler option (assuming you know the correct package name):

```
$ cpp -H -o /dev/null $(pkg-config --cflags gdk-2.0) - <<<'#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>'|&head -n1
. /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h
```

To find the package name on my system, I queried `pkg-config` itself, and then guessed which one was desired:

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep gdk
gdk-pixbuf-2.0                 GdkPixbuf - Image loading and scaling
gdk-2.0                        GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit (x11 target)
gdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0            GdkPixbuf Xlib - GdkPixbuf rendering for Xlib
gdk-x11-2.0                    GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit (x11 target)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the command:

```
find /usr/include -name gdkkeysyms.h
```

in your bash. The include folder under the Unix System Resources (`usr` or `/usr/local` or `opt` depends on how it was installed) directory has all the directories you probably want. Try this syntax whenever you want to look at source code:

```
find /usr/include -name header_name.h
```

### References

[How to view source code of header file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170637/5768336)

**Note(For C++):**

> C++ headers would be in  `/usr/include/c++`

Comment: FYI `/usr/` is 'Unix System Resources', not 'user' ;). `/home` would be the 'user directory' (really `/home/$USER/` or `~/`. The `include` folder in the 'user directory' would instead be `~/include/` probably.

Comment: Just nitpicking :P.

Comment: @amanuel2 Could still reside in `/usr/local` or `/opt` or elsewhere. Depends how it was installed.

Comment: Another FYI and more nitpicking, C++ headers would be in `/usr/include/c++`, e.g., on my machine, C++ headers are in `/usr/include/c++/4.6/`.

Comment: @RastaJedi sorry i had to go next class , thanks for the pointer , i put it up now :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry i had to go to my next class , thanks for the pointer on those different directories where your usr might be in depending on your installation technique. its up now :).